# Failing to submit spark job through Livy programmatic client api

Tags: java, apache-spark, livy

I'm trying to use submit simple word count program which was implemented with java8, spark 2.4.7, and submitted through Livy 0.7. I have three containers which runs on my local computer. One for Spark driver, one for Spark worker and one for Livy.

I use the Livy's client to submit the program as follows:

```
private static final String LIVY_URL = "http://localhost:8998/";
private static final String JAR_PATH = "/.../spark-word-count/target/word-count-0.1- 
SNAPSHOT.jar";

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    LivyClient livyClient = new LivyClientBuilder(false)
    .setURI(new URI(LIVY_URL)).build();
    
    try {
        System.err.printf("Uploading %s to the Spark context...\n", JAR_PATH);
        livyClient.uploadJar(new File(JAR_PATH)).get();
        
        System.err.printf("Running JavaWordCount...\n", JAR_PATH);
        double returnValue = livyClient.submit(new JavaWordCount()).get();
      
        System.out.println("Application return value is: " + returnValue);
      } finally {
        livyClient.stop(true);
      }
}
```

And I'm getting the following error:

> Caused by: java.io.IOException: Bad Request: {"msg":"requirement
> failed: Local path
> /root/.livy-sessions/b78e9935-70b4-4fe7-8840-8c84067fbd52/word-count-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
> cannot be added to user sessions."}

Looking at Livy's UI, I can see that a session starts,
and when I attach to Livy's running container I can see my Jar uploaded to /root/.livy-sessions, but then it fails with the error above.

The docker-compose file that I use pointing LIVY_FILE_LOCAL_DIR_WHITELIST to /opt/jars.
I saw that people suggest to change it to the location where the Jar is uploaded to, I indeed change it to /root/.livy-sessions, but I'm getting some other error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
> java.io.IOException: Internal Server Error:
> "java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.RuntimeException:
> py4j.Py4JException: Error while obtaining a new communication channel

I will really appreciate any help! thanks...